# How group by date and resource with FullCalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, resources, fullcalendar, grouping

I use FullCalendar to generate my agenda with 3 sections each day. I add attribute groupByDateAndResource and resources like there:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDayTrucks'
    },
    views: {
        agendaDayTrucks: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { day: 1 },
            buttonText: 'Truck View Per Day'
        }
    },
    buttonText: {
        week: 'Week View'
    },
    nowIndicator: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    slotDuration: '01:00:00',
    snapDuration: '00:05:00',
    groupByDateAndResource: true,
    resources: [
        { id: 'truck1', title: 'Truck 1' },
        { id: 'truck2', title: 'Truck 2' },
        { id: 'truck3', title: 'Truck 3' }
    ]
    ...
});
```

My calendar show perfectly, but my columns doesn't divided in 3 sections. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4uZ2.png)

How can I make divide all my days in sections with FullCalendar.js?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

I installed [extension scheduler.js](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/). This extension of FullCalender display all my resources exactly like I want.

Comment: You need to divide cell by your own, FullCalendar created tables for header and body, so each cell is "td", you will have to divide it into sub cell by your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this, This is in header, and in body you will have to divide cells again.

[image]

Comment: FullCalendar.js is a library and it's generated interne. How can I divide cells if I don't know how he works?

Comment: With javaScript/jQuery you can override library functions and play around as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDayTrucks'
},
 groupByDateAndResource: true,
  views: {
    agendaDayTrucks: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { day: 1 },
        buttonText: 'Truck View Per Day'
    }
},
buttonText: {
    week: 'Week View'
},
nowIndicator: true,
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
defaultDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
slotDuration: '01:00:00',
snapDuration: '00:05:00',
groupByDateAndResource: true,
resources: [
    { id: 'truck1', title: 'Truck 1' },
    { id: 'truck2', title: 'Truck 2' },
    { id: 'truck3', title: 'Truck 3' }
]
...
 });
```

you have to put groupByDateAndResource: true
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/groupByDateAndResource